# Having serious problems with Disqus

Tags: laravel, comments, laravel-5.5, disqus

I'm using Laravel to make a blog and so i decided to use disqus for the comment section but every time i try to use disqus (to login for instance) i keep getting this error : CSRF verification failed (403).

Comment: I'm currently using disqus in my website i simply added their code to my blade without need of define any route erc. and login for users to comment is base on disqus website login not mine. not sure if it helps just sharing experience.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris):

> You may also exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the `$except` property of the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware

```
protected $except = [
    'disqus/*'
];
```